# Hash Method Issues, get method specifically

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, hashtable

So, I am in  a Data Structures class and we are writing code and varying methods for Hashing. I am actually having trouble with the "get" method. The tests we have run fine until the last "key9" which is asserted to return null. The for loop for some reasons exits and the keyStartIndex is instantiated again. The method is not recursive so I have no idea why this is transpiring. Code is below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Method I am trying to complete, that is having issues.

```
...
public String get(String key) {
        //TODO : complete the method
int keyStartIndex = (int) hashFunction(key) % items.length;

        for(int i = keyStartIndex; i < items.length; i++){
            if(items[i].key == hashFunction(key)){
                return items[i].item;
            } else if(i == items.length-1){
                i=0;
                continue;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
...
```

---

All prior code in this class that applies to this method

```
...
import java.util.Arrays;

import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Value;

class DataItem {
    long key;
    String item;

    public DataItem(long key, String item) {
        this.key = key;
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%s:%s}", key, item);
    }
}

public class HashMap {
    private int size = 0;
    private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int DELETED_KEY = 0;
    private DataItem[] items;
    
    public HashMap() {
        items = new DataItem[INITIAL_SIZE];
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public long hashFunction(String key) {
        long hashed = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++){
            hashed += key.charAt(i)*(Math.pow(27, i));
        }

        return hashed;
    }

    public void put(String key, String value) throws TableIsFullException {
        if (size >= items.length-1){
            throw new TableIsFullException();
        } else {

            DataItem input = new DataItem(hashFunction(key), value);
            
            for(int i = ((int) input.key % items.length); i < items.length; i++){
                if(items[i] != null){
                    continue;
                 }else if(i == items.length - 1 && items[i] != null){
                     i = 0; 
                     continue;
                 } else {
                     items[i] = input;
                     size++;
                     break;
                 }

                }

            } 
        }
...
```

----------------------------------------------And the tests that are being ran, only the last one is failing again, with "key9". I have ran debugger and it says there is a nullPointerException. Again, with break points, for some reason it leaves the for loop and processes another key, key3 to be specific. I have no idea why this is happening.

```
 @Test
    public void testGet() throws TableIsFullException {
        map.put("key1", "value1");
        map.put("key2", "value2");
        map.put("key3", "value3");
        map.put("key4", "value4");
        map.put("key5", "value5");
        map.put("key6", "value6");
        assertEquals("value3", map.get("key3"));
        assertEquals(null, map.get("key9"));   
    }
```

Comment: `i == items.length - 1 && items[i] != null` will never be triggered

Comment: Also, of this is Java, please add the appropriate tag

Comment: Actually, that section of conditions triggers just fine and the tests excute for the put method. I am having issues with the get method. Will update the tags appropriately.

Comment: That's just because the tests don't trigger the problem, not because it's implemented correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `put` and `get` methods don't implement wraparound correctly. That means that when you get a couple of hash collisions towards the end of the table, things go haywire.

Secondly, you are not handling hash collisions correctly in either method. The contract for hash is that `obj1.equals(obj2)` implies `hash1 == hash2`, but not the other way around. That means that `DataItem` **must** record the original object as well as the hash. I will assume that you've added the appropriate field, and that `DataItem` now has three fields names `key`, `hash` and `value`.

Let's start with `put`:

1. The end condition is `i >= items.length`, so you either have an infinite loop if you wrap around, or you never wrap around.
2. Since you check `items[i] != null` first, `i == items.length - 1 && items[i] != null` can never be triggered, and so you never wrap around when the end of the table is full.
3. You never check if the existing item matches the new key.

One way to correct `put` is too treat `items` as a circular buffer. That means that you subtract off an offset modulo `items.length`:

```
int hash = hashFunction(key);
int offset = hash % items.length);
            
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    int k = (i + offset) % items.length;
    if(items[k] == null) {
        items[k] = new DataItem(key, hash, value);
        size++;
        break;
    }
    if(items[k].hash == hash && items[k].key.equals(key)) {
        items[k].value = value;
        break;
    }
}
```

You also need to fix your size check before throwing an exception. Checking `size >= items.length - 1` will throw an exception when there is one free slot available. The correct condition is

```
if(size >= items.length) {
```

Your `get` method suffers from the same issue with wraparound as `put`. It also has the problem that you're checking for hash equality and not object equality when you retrieve an object.

```
int hash = hashFunction(key);
int offset = hash % items.length;
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    int k = (i + offset) % items.length
    if(items[k].hash == hash && items[k].key.equals(key)){
        return items[i].value;
    }
}
return null;
```

The check `items[k].item.equals(key)` is critical for resolving hash collisions correctly. Notice that it is only performed when the hashes match because of short circuiting.

Try to avoid recomputing values like `hash` inside a loop.

This whole scheme breaks down if you try to support a `remove` operation. If you notice, `put` will stop searching for matches once it finds an empty slot. This will break down if you can create empty slots before the matching object.

Answer (score 1):

The NullPointerException that you see occurs because in the `get()` method you write

```
if(items[i].key == hashFunction(key))
```

Now if the specific key has not been added to the `HashMap` (and the `items` array is not yet full) the entry `items[i]` is still `null` and trying to access `items[i].key` gives the NullPointerException that you see.

The shortest test case for leads to your problem is:

```
@Test
public void keyNotFound() throws TableIsFullException {
    assertEquals(null, map.get("key9"));   
}
```

Besides that, carefully read the answer of "Mad Physicist" because it addresses other design flaws in your implementation (although not this one).